# Problem with signal handlers

Tags: c, process, signals

how can something print 3 times when it only goes the printing code twice? I'm coding in C and the code is in a SIGCHLD signal handler I created.

```
void chld_signalHandler() {
 int pidadf = (int) getpid();
 printf("pidafdfaddf: %d\n", pidadf);

 while (1) {
  int termChildPID = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);

  if (termChildPID == 0 || termChildPID == -1) {
   break;
  }

  dll_node_t *temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL) {
   printf("stuff\n");
   if (temp->pid == termChildPID && temp->type == WORK) {
    printf("inside if\n");

    // read memory mapped file b/w WORKER and MAIN
    // get statistics and write results to pipe
    char resultString[256];

    // printing TIME
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
     sprintf(resultString, "TIME; %d ; %d ; %d ; %s\n",i,1,2,temp->stats->mboxFileName);
     fwrite(resultString, strlen(resultString), 1, pipeFD);
    }

    remove_node(temp);
    break;
   }
   temp = temp->next;
  }
  printf("done printing from sigchld \n");
 }
 return;
}
```

the output for my MAIN process is this:

```
MAIN PROCESS 16214 created WORKER PROCESS 16220 for file class.sp10.cs241.mbox
pidafdfaddf: 16214
stuff
stuff
inside if
done printing from sigchld 
MAIN PROCESS 16214 created WORKER PROCESS 16221 for file class.sp10.cs225.mbox
pidafdfaddf: 16214
stuff
stuff
inside if
done printing from sigchld
```

and the output for the MONITOR process is this:

```
MONITOR: pipe is open for reading
MONITOR PIPE: TIME; 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; class.sp10.cs225.mbox
MONITOR PIPE: TIME; 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; class.sp10.cs225.mbox
MONITOR PIPE: TIME; 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; class.sp10.cs241.mbox
MONITOR: end of readpipe
```

( I've taken out repeating lines so I don't take up so much space )

Thanks,
Hristo

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597084/problem-with-signal-handlers-being-called-too-many-times

Comment: it is a duplicate because someone closed my post without giving me a chance to respond.

Comment: If your question was closed the first time, what makes you think it'll do any better the 2nd?  Don't post duplicates, and at least come up with a real title.

Comment: You just asked this question. Also, at least change it when it gets closed to something that won't get closed again.

Comment: Also, your code is not formatted and your tags are bad.  Surely you could do better than `output`.  What language you used would certainly help.  Remember: tags connect your question to an audience.  The wrong tags and your question is doomed because no one will see it.  If you want us to put effort into solving your question, you need to put more effort into asking it.

Comment: What you need to do is go back and **edit your original question**, so that the code is formatted better, it has a descriptive title, and is tagged (read: categorized) correctly.  Then go post to meta.stackoverflow.com explaining that you fixed that question and beg for people to vote to re-open it.

Comment: @Joel Coahoorn: It was closed before his edit, because the question had no sense at that time. It's not a dupe of his original question, it's just a normal attempt of posting the question properly this time.

Comment: @Hristo, we did a bit of rework on the original question and it will hopefully be re-opened. This one suffers from all the problems your original had PLUS it's a duplicate. You should wait until the original is re-opened. If it hasn't for a day then delete it and re-ask (with all the improvements).

Comment: I'm not looking for votes or ratings or repertoire. I was just simply looking for an answer to a bug that made no sense. Granted I didn't specify ANYTHING, I didn't get a chance to before it was closed... I didn't even know that a post can be "closed". 

In the end, I found my answer. I'll wait a day and try this again. Thanks for your feedback everyone. I'm sorry for pissing people off...

Comment: @Hristo, if you're pissing people off, that's _their_ problem, not yours. Don't sweat it. I just tried to explain how things are usually done around these parts. Well, how _I_ would do things, others may have different ideas :-)  Newcomers get a little leeway because they're new but it's still a good idea to educate them.

Comment: @paxdiablo, Well thanks for your help. I haven't come across this type of situation, and I've been posting for about 6 months, so it just caught me off guard... as if people are yelling at me for asking a bad question. My bad guys... I'll know for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the small amount of information we have...

1. The main process creates worker process with pid = 16220
2. Worker process 16220 runs and terminates
3. The signal handler runs and apparently the second node in the "head" list has a record for process id 16220 ("stuff" prints twice and "inside if" prints once).
4. The main process creates worker process with pid = 16221
5. Worker process 16221 runs and terminates
6. The signal handler runs and apparently the second node in the "head" list has the record for process id 16221 ("stuff" prints twice and "inside if" prints once).

That is about all we can glean from the data you have provided. If you were to pass a stat parameter for to waitpid you could see why the worker processes terminated by printing out termChildPID and the termination reason in the handler.

If your question is why does "stuff" print twice then take a look at what "head" points to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured out my problem and fixed it.